# Should I use my personal admin user or create a dedicated 'ansible' user for SSH in Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible, root

I'm starting learining and using ansible and struggling a bit with the user ansible uses for ssh.

Is ansible supposed to use my personal admin user to ssh onto the invetory hosts and escalate priviliges there if needed or is it a better way to create a service user called "ansible" on each inventory host with sudo rights so ansible can use this dedicated user for all of its stuff?

if there is dedicated "ansible" user I could store the private key on the ansible server and limit the ssh ability on the hosts for that user to the asible server ip.

Is there any guideline on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

This a topic where there is probably no objective best solution  and you'll get arguments supporting both options.

I'm strongly opposed to "shared" accounts.

*Often more and more people will get access to shared accounts and passwords won't get changed regularly or at all. When people leave/change roles too often they'll still have privileged access, because revoking their personal (admin) accounts and privileges  doesn't revoke their access to such shared accounts.  Eventually nobody feels accountable for the shared account anymore and/or the impact of changing the password and/or revoking access rights can't be overseen and nobody will want to enter that minefield anymore.*

As a security conscious administrator I want to have an audit trail where logins/actions/changes can be attributed to specific team members and administrators.

So when I run a playbook from my workstation, I'll authenticate  with  my personal account. When my colleague is developing a new playbook, they run them with their own personal credentials. All administrators have full `sudo` rights already anyway.

---

In addition to personal accounts we have AWX ; the plays that launched from there will run with the credentials of a specific  functional account dedicated to AWX, but there will be an audit trail in AWX with accounting which schedule and/or whom launched the play.

Access to the functional account reserved for AWX access should be restricted ( i.e. with options in the `˜/.ssh/authorized_keys`  file and/or a User Match in the `sshd_config`) so even when an admin gets access to the private key used by AWX they can't use it from their own workstation to run/develop playbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So maybe I got a little bit confused here. I was thinking about installing Ansible on a dedicated server and let every sysadmin use that server via ssh.

Is ansible really meant to be used decentral, directly on the sysadmins workstation?
That way I could provide my inventory and playbooks via git repos.

Comment: Yes, your inventory and playbooks should be under version control. Again you want to have both personal accountability of who made what changes, and should work towards  a review process of changes people make to playbooks. and you don't want a whole team working on a single set of files where one admin making improvements to a playbook can block the other from running it.

Comment: So I dont need a centralized ansible server but rather install ansible on every linux sysadmin worstation?

From a quick google search I saw that AWX is centralized - In what kind of szenario would I want to use that? For API requests from Jenkis or something?

Comment: A centralized ansible server may make sense, for example when the workstations of your admins don't have direct access to the systems they're managing. A central Ansible server may also be useful to ensure that everybody is using the same Ansible version and modules. But even their it will be useful that everybody works on their own feature branches and you have version management, commits and define releases etc. For us it makes more sense that everybody works on  their own work station. As I started with: there is no objective best solution, whatever works for you

Answer (score 0):

Create a dedicated "ansible" user on the remote hosts.

See:

- [Ansible: Control User Requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072833/ansible-control-user-requirements/54073719#54073719).
- [How can I auth as different users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715746/how-can-i-auth-as-different-users-without-creating-multiple-hosts-in-ansible/71715977#71715977)
- [Ansible remote_user: root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424995/ansible-remote-user-root-ssh-permission-denied-publickey/57425927#57425927)

The best practice is to put your public key into the *authorized_keys* of this "ansible" user. Create the user and allow a passwordless sudo for the "ansible" user on the remote host.

You don't have to create SSH keys for "ansible" user on the remote hosts. The [ssh connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#ansible-builtin-ssh-connection-connect-via-ssh-client-binary) doesn't need it when you connect the "ansible" user on the remote host from the controller.

---

Q: *"What do you mean by "You don't have to create SSH keys for "ansible" user on the remote hosts"? I still need to put down my public key on the remote hosts ansible user ssh config, right?"*

A: Right. You need to put your public key into the ansible user file *.ssh/authorized_keys* on the remote host. For example,

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 find .ssh
.ssh
.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I mean you don't need the SSH keys(e.g. id_rsa, id_rsa.pub) on the remote hosts. For example,

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_12 find .ssh
.ssh
.ssh/authorized_keys
.ssh/id_rsa              <-- not needed
.ssh/id_rsa.pub          <-- not needed
.ssh/known_hosts         <-- not needed
```

See: [SSH Protocol](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/protocol)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

What do you mean by "You don't have to create SSH keys for "ansible" user on the remote hosts"?

I still need to put down my public key on the remote hosts ansible user ssh config, right?